# VirtualBox VM settings between different CPUs (Processor/Acceleration)

Tags: virtualbox

I have 2 PCs, 1 with a INTEL-Q9550 (YES-VT-x) and another with INTEL-E2160 (NO-VT-x)

I will be using the Q9550 first to create a new VM, install XP and install stuff I'll need. Once this VM is golden, I plan on migrating this VM over to the E2160 machine.

The question is, while creating/preparing this VM on the Q9550, should I disable all the following settings below to make sure the E2160 can start this VM without errors?

```
Q9550 Default VM Settings
=========================

PROCESSOR
  [X] Enable PAE/NX

ACCELERATION
  [X] Enable VT-x/AMD-V
  [X] Enable Nested Paging
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I built a VM on the Q9550 with the above settings all enabled and then later migrated it to the E2160, so far the E2160 is running the VM without problems.

To answer my own question: no, it's not necessary to disable any of the ACCELERATION settings to successfully boot the VM on the E2160 CPU.